# Pullback preserves cokernel

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, limits-colimits

Is that true that in an abelian category $\mathcal{C}$, if I have the pullback diagram:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
P @>{p_1}>> C\\
@V{p_2}VV @V{g}VV \\
A @>{f}>> B
\end{CD}
$$

with $f$ and $p_1$ monomorphisms, then $Coker(f) = Coker(p_1)$?

Comment: There's no reason for that to be true. Take $C = 0$, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Nope! Let $C = 0$, for example.

What *is* true is that $\text{Coker}(p_1) \to \text{Coker}(f)$ is a monomorphism.

(it doesn't matter whether or not $f$ and $p_1$ are monomorphisms)

Comment: Yeah sure, it was just an adjoint that I wrote, 'cause is in the case that I'm studyng, is not so important. Thank you so much!

Comment: What if I add the hypothesis that $g$ and $p_2$ are epimorphisms?

Comment: If $g$ is an epimorphism, then the map of cokernels is also an epimorphism.

Comment: I was looking again at this question and I can't get, at the moment, why the map between the two cokernels is a monomorphism. Can you explain?

Comment: @freedfromthereal: $\operatorname{coker}(p_1)$ is isomorphic to the image of the composite $C \xrightarrow{g} B \to \operatorname{coker}(f)$. I don't recall an easy way to see this; I only know an argument with elements (construct the inverse map), or maybe spectral sequence argument. If it helps, note that $\ker(p_1) \cong \ker(f)$ as well.